# Logarithmic complexity: Either the book has a typo or what's happening here?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I am going through algorithms now and I've faced one example where I answered as an `Infinite loop` but in the correct answers, it says it's `O(log2n)`.

```
function someFunc(n) {

    for(var i = 0; i < n; i * 2) { // I think that Infinite loop cannot be O(log2n), can it?
        console.log(i);
    }

}
```

I am a bit puzzled here. I don't understand why because it's the same as the `Infinite loop` below, no?

```
function loop(n) {

    while(true) {
        console.log(n)
    }

}
```

Source: Sammie Bae - JavaScript Data Structures and Algorithms - 2019 (Chapter 1)

Comment: Seems like typo, probably should be `i *= 2`, and would have to start with 1 at least.  I'm guessing it's not meant to actually be runnable code, but more to show you what O(logN) would look like.

Comment: Did you look to see if there are errata for the book?

Comment: This would terminate: `for(var i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)`

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < n; i * 2) ` is not an infinite loop for `n<0`

Comment: The `i = 0` part bothers me a lot more than the `*` vs `*=`...

Comment: @JasonGoemaat 100% agree, that's why I was surprised to see that and I thought why maybe I don't understand something. Maybe bad publication I suppose

Comment: @GACy20 Agree here

Comment: LOL, I misread it too.

Comment: @midnight_dev definitely a bad publication... check if there exists some Errata for the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clear error in the book. I found [a PDF of chapter 1 on the publisher's website](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4842-3988-9_1.pdf) which is exactly as you say (p.10) :

> EXERCISE 5
>
> ```
> 1   function someFunction(n) {
>
> 2
>
> 3       for (var i=0;i<n;i*2) {
>
> 4           console.log(n);
>
> 5       }
>
> 6
>
> 7   }
> ```

(next page)

> Answers
> [...]
> 5. O(log2n) Logarithmic complexity. For a given n, this will operate only log2n  times because i is incremented by multiplying by 2 rather
> than adding 1 as in the other examples.

As noted in comments, this loop will in fact never exit.

The author (probably) maintains a github repo where the source can be found, so you could propose a fix to [the relevant file](https://github.com/Apress/js-data-structures-and-algorithms/blob/master/Chapter1(Big-O%20Notation).js)

Comment: If you read on, there are other typos as well. The book wasn’t reviewed or it’s not the author’s main language I suppose